# do.call specify environment inside function

Tags: r, do.call

I'm using the following construct in a package,

```
## two functions in the global environment
funa <- function(x) x^2
funb <- function(x) x^3
## called within a function, fine
fun_wrap <- function(){
  lapply(c('funa', 'funb'), do.call, list(x=3))
}

fun_wrap()
[[1]]
[1] 9

[[2]]
[1] 27
```

but I've just been bitten by the fact that it won't work if the functions are in a different (local) frame,

```
## same construct, but the functions are local
fun_wrap1 <- function(){
  funa1 <- function(x) x^2
  funb1 <- function(x) x^3
  lapply(c('funa1', 'funb1'), do.call, list(x=3))
}
## now it fails
fun_wrap1()
##Error in FUN(c("funa1", "funb1")[[1L]], ...) : 
##  could not find function "funa1"
```

I've tried passing `envir=parent.frame(2)` to `do.call()` (doesn't work); frankly the help page of `?parent.frame` goes way over my head. Any hint for a more robust use of do.call?

Note that the list of functions comes as a character vector, passed from another piece of code; I prefer not to pass the functions directly.

*Edit:* one more twist... I thought I'd illustrated the right problem with my toy example, but the actual code I'm using is slightly different, in the sense that I'm calling `fun_wrap1` within a separate function. The proposed solutions fail in this context.

```
fun_wrap1 <- function(funs){
  lapply(funs, do.call, args=list(x=3), envir=environment())
}

foo <- function(){
  funa1 <- function(x) x^2
  funb1 <- function(x) x^3
 fun_wrap1(c('funa1', 'funb1'))
}

foo()
##Error in FUN(c("funa1", "funb1")[[1L]], ...) : 
##  could not find function "funa1"
```

(and the same happens with the `match.fun` approach)

I can get it to work by passing an optional environment to `fun_wrap1`,

```
fun_wrap1 <- function(funs, e=parent.frame()){
  lapply(funs, do.call, args=list(x=3), envir=e)
}

foo <- function(){
  funa1 <- function(x) x^2
  funb1 <- function(x) x^3
  fun_wrap1(c('funa1', 'funb1'))
}

foo()
```

and that's hopefully it.

Comment: sorry about the constant changes, I'd failed to properly identify the target when I wrote the first iteration.

Comment: In your revised example that fails, the new function should be changed to: `fun_wrap1 <- function(funs, envir = parent.frame()) {
  lapply(funs, do.call, args=list(x=3), envir=envir)
}`  The `foo` function can stay as it is.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed it according to your advice.

Comment: You don't need `environment()` in `foo`.

Comment: even better! Boy, I really need to get my head around those things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work, but i'm not sure if it has other implications I'm not considering:

```
fun_wrap1 <- function(){
  funa1 <- function(x) x^2
  funb1 <- function(x) x^3
  lapply(c('funa1', 'funb1'), do.call, args=list(x=3), envir=environment())
}

fun_wrap1()
#[[1]]
#[1] 9
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 27
```

So this is essentially equivalent to having the `lapply` statement as:

```
lapply(
       c('funa1', 'funb1'), 
       function(f) do.call(f, args=list(x=3), envir=environment() )
      )
```

Comment: @baptiste - it should probably be `args=list(x=3)` to be really explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Evidently if we evaluate the functions in `fun_wrap2` it works.  The problem with the approach in the question is that the character strings get converted to functions inside one of the processing functions which changes the lookup path.

```
fun_wrap2 <- function(){

  funa1 <- function(x) x^2
  funb1 <- function(x) x^3

  nms <- c("funa1", "funb1")
  funs <- lapply(nms, match.fun)
  lapply(funs, do.call, list(x=3))

}

fun_wrap2()
```

Comment: that makes sense, thanks for the added explanation. I've since realised that my problem is slightly different though, and I can't get this approach to work there (see Edit)

Comment: while I really appreciate the help, i've accepted the other answer as it clarified the explicit passing of the right environment, which was key to the problem. `match.fun` achieved the same here, but perhaps not as explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler version of @g-grothendieck's answer. Rather than using the function names, we just put the functions themselves into the list that is fed to `lapply`.

```
fun_wrap1 <- function(){
  funa1 <- function(x) x^2
  funb1 <- function(x) x^3
  lapply(list(funa1, funb1), do.call, list(x=3))
}

fun_wrap1()
```

Comment: That was my original answer but he indicated in the comments that the input must be a character vector of names so I changed it.