# How does the envir option of do.call work?

Tags: r

The documentation of `do.call` states:

> If `quote` is `FALSE`, the default, then the arguments are evaluated (in the calling environment, not in `envir`).

This sentence would suggest to me that when `quote = FALSE`, specifying `envir` makes no difference. However, that's not the case, and in fact I've encountered cases where I need to specify `envir` to get the function to work.

Simplest reproducible example:

```
g1 <- function(x) {
  args <- as.list(match.call())
  args[[1]] <- NULL # remove the function call
  do.call(print, args, quote = FALSE) # call print()
}

g2 <- function(x) {
  args <- as.list(match.call())
  args[[1]] <- NULL # remove the function call
  do.call(print, args, quote = FALSE, envir = parent.frame()) # call print(), specifying envir
}

h1 <- function(x, y) {
  g1(x*y)
}

h2 <- function(x, y) {
  g2(x*y)
}
```

With these functions, `h2()` behaves as one would think but `h1()` does not:

```
h1(2, 3)
#Error in print(x) : object 'y' not found

h2(2, 3)
#[1] 6

y <- 100
h1(2, 3)
#[1] 600 
## Looks like g1() took the value of y from the global environment

h2(2, 3)
#[1] 6
```

Can anybody explain to me what's going on here?

Note: There's a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028488/do-call-specify-environment-inside-function) but by my reading the answers don't specifically state what `do.call()` does with the `envir` variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`?do.call` says:

> envir
>   an environment within which to evaluate the call. This will be
>   most useful if what is a character string and the arguments are
>   symbols or quoted expressions.

We can easily illustrate this if the `what=` argument of `do.call` is a character string.  Then `envir=` determines where it is looked up.

```
e <- new.env()
e$f <- function() 2
f <- function() 3
do.call("f", list())
## [1] 3
do.call("f", list(), envir = e)
## [1] 2
```

The same is true for the arguments as the code in the question shows.  Note that the arguments are already quoted since `match.call()` is being used.

What is happening in the case of `h1` and `g1` is that this is effectively run within `g1`

```
do.call(print, list(call("*", quote(x), quote(y))), quote = FALSE)
```

Now it finds `x` in `g1` (since `g1` has one argument `x`) but there is no `y` in `g1` so it looks to the parent environment of `g1` which is the global environment where it finds `y`.

In the case of `h2` and `g2` it runs this in `g2`:

```
do.call(print, list(call("*", quote(x), quote(y))), quote = FALSE, envir = parent.frame())
```

and it finds `x` and `y` in `h2` which is the parentframe of `g2`.

Note that the parent environment is not the same as the parent frame:

- the parent environment is determined by where the function was *defined* so if the function was defined in the global environment then its parent environment is the global environment.
- the parent frame is the environment of the caller

Comment: Thanks. So I take it then that `quote=FALSE` has no effect on this case and the call in `g2` is the correct way to do it if I want to simulate a regular function call?